# How to set plot area width and height in Highcharts?

Tags: plot, highcharts

I'm plotting a map made by a series of points in HighCharts. I want that map to be properly scaled and be a perfect square.

Thus, i've set the chart height and width at the same value:

```
$(function () {
    $('#map-container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            height: 225,
            width: 225
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            min: <?php echo $lat_bon_min; ?>,
            max: <?php echo $lat_bon_max; ?>,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            }

        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            min: <?php echo $lon_bon_min; ?>,
            max: <?php echo $lon_bon_max; ?>,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            }

        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,  
            type: 'scatter',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: map_data,
            keys: ['time', 'x', 'y']
        }]

    });
});
```

The problem is that the chart container is a square, but the plot area is not.

I made a screenshot of the result. Red line is the map, black square is the chart container (which is a perfect square), blue rectangle is the plot area which you can see is not a square.

[image]

How can i set plot area size in order to make it a perfect square?

Comment: you can set margin:0 in chart config, but it takes space for labels,title,credit etc because of which its not 225X225. apart from the plotted area there are placeholders for these info

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi that's what i thought. The problem is that i want to make the plot area of a specific size no matter what labels,credits, legends, etc...are there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend Highcharts with new function. Here you can find information about extending Highcharts:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

As you will see in my demo, I wrapped setChartSize function and give them possibility to use parameters from your chart options:

```
chart: {
  plotAreaWidth: 300,
  plotAreaHeight: 200
},
```

Function is also positioning your plot area in the middle of chart container.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/eph5secj/2/

Comment: Hi tried to implement it but found that there are bugs in your code, where there are issues with rendering the height, width and y ( see console log in your fiddle). Any idea why it happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731089/how-to-set-plot-width-specifically-in-highchartsexcluding-the-labels  . Hi I posted similar issue on this. Any advise?   @Grzegorz Blachlinski

Answer (score 0):

In your chart default values of [`spacing`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacing) are used and the biggest is a bottom spacing with value of `15` while others are of value `10` each. When setting all spacing to `15` you will get a square (`196 x 196 px`).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5825mzLs/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, `marginTop` and `marginBottom` properties.

> The margin options (marginLeft, marginTop etc) give the margin to the actual plot area and does not apply to other elements on the chart (labels, legend etc)

See example in Hightscharts Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style