# Highcharts specify height of plot area only

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart in Highcharts. The x-axis labels can vary in height. Currently I have the chart "height" property set to 200. This makes the height of the entire chart, including the x-axis labels 200 pixels. So if the x-axis labels are taller, the plot area gets shortened.

[image: plot with tall labels] [image: plot with short labels]

As you can see the two plots are the same overall height but the actual size of the bars is different. I would rather set the height of the plot area and let the labels take up as much space below as they need. As far as I can tell there is no simple way to set the height of the plot area, does anyone have any ideas (possibly how to set the height of the y-axis ticks or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent so long fiddling around with this before posting the question, and then of course found the solution right after asking.

```
chart: {
    type: "column",
    height: 220,
    marginBottom: 100,
}
```

By setting the marginBottom to a number large enough to encompass the tall and short labels, the charts are now consistent. This is still not my favorite solution and I would love a way to enforce a height of the plot area itself, but this is what solved my specific issue this time.

Comment: You could also use a solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956950/how-to-set-plot-area-width-and-height-in-highcharts, by @Grzegorz Blachliński

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pane: {
      size: 300 //here you can give number or string or percantege
    }
```

This solution required [highchart-more](https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js)