# Highcharts same scale steps (equal tick interval) on x and y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make fixed width and height for ticks but leave chart being resizable.

I've tried properties:

```
tickInterval
tickPixelInterval
```

But these properties are not work together. Is there any way to make "cells" square without making calculations and setting min/max?

Data on chart are dinamically load.

[image: Chart]

Comment: You can use the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956950/how-to-set-plot-area-width-and-height-in-highcharts by @Grzegorz Blachliński, to change `plotAreaWidth` and `plotAreaHeight`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/eph5secj/2/.

Comment: @d_paul, thank you for suggestion. However I don't need plot area to be square, I actually need same tick size in pixels and in values, and because of it setting min/max dinamically looks much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural that the space between ticks is changing along with resizing chart but if you want to preserve the same pixel value between them, you need to perform calculation how many ticks to show, so the `tickPixelInterval` be the same. You can also add a scrollbar, to have access to hidden range but you require Highstock for that. Take a look at the example posted below and in case of any question, feel free to ask.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPixelInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rq4fxt6j/

Comment: Thank you! I found good ideas about how to make it. I'll implement these ideas today evening and report back if I'll make chart resizable and not scrollable.