# Fixed plot height in scatter chart

Tags: highcharts

I have been searching this but not able to get any solutions for this. I want my scatter chart to be of fixed height regardless of no of legends used.

Please look into below fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/3o982ewu/118/

```
"chart": {
    "type": "scatter",
    "zoomType": "xy",
    "plotBorderWidth": 2,
    "width": 400,
    "height":400,
.....
```

I have set chart height to be 400. If no of legends increase, then scatter chart height gets adjusted (decrease) accordingly. You can try increasing the legends and notice that chart height gets decreased. I have tried other options like setting margin top and bottom (suggested in one post) but no luck. 
I see that in highcharts js, there is `'plotHeight'` variable which is used to set the chart height but I find no means to set it from my code or provide into as chart options. This scatter chart will be displayed in pdf so there is no scope of adding pagination, scrolls or any other stuff which is feasible only in web browser but not in pdf.

Comment: Using marginBottom, you should be able to achieve this. Here I have set `marginBottom: 100`: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/3o982ewu/147/. Is this the solution you want? If not, what should be different?

Comment: @ewolden With this marginBottom solution, legends are overlapping the scatter chart. I don't want that

Comment: You can also set the `maxHeight` property on the legend. The legend will be paginated if it exceeds the available space. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3o982ewu/158/

Comment: This topic can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956950/how-to-set-plot-area-width-and-height-in-highcharts

Comment: @jlbriggs I don't want the legends to be paginated either. This scatter chart is shown inside a pdf. So there is no scope of adding pagination, scroll bars. Edited the question.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when the legend is too large for the space available? You seem to be asking to allow a legend of any size to fit into a fixed space, which is not plausible. You can play with the legend item style, margin, distance, etc, but you're still going to hit a problem at some point if the number of legend items can reach any limit. If you are talking about a set chart, and not a dynamic one, then provide the actual example that will be used. If it's going to be dynamic, you have to make some decisions.

Comment: @jlbriggs Legends could be of any size. I just want my chart plot size to be fixed. (the square box of the chart). Whole chart area image (incl legends) could be of any size.

Comment: Hm. You might be able to capture the size of the legend box in the chart's load event, and expand your chart container size accordingly. Or, if you don't care how tall the total chart is, just make it bigger than it will need to be, and let the legend fill the space as needed.

Comment: @jlbriggs Added the solution we did as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I found a way to deal with this scenario.

We hid the legends on the chart, so this way plot height of the chart will be always fixed. (plotHeight will be equal to the height of the chart which we provide in the chart settings considering we don't supply any margins)
We stored the data points (color of the legend and legend name) in the array and printed those outside the chart to make them appear as legends.